# Cannot create Anaconda environment tensorflow

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, environment

I'm trying to create an Anaconda environment named `tensorflow`, following the installing guide on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Unfortunately, both in the Anaconda prompt and in the Windows command prompt, when I type `conda create -n tensorflow` , it returns

```
Fetching package metadata .............


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '
```

And when I try to create a new environment named ''tensorflow'' in the 'Environments' section of Anaconda Navigator, I get the following error in a popup box:

```
C:\Users\Hugo\Anaconda3\Anaconda3New\python.exe
C:\Users\Hugo\Anaconda3\Anaconda3New\Scripts\conda-script.py create --yes --json --mkdir 
  --name tensorflow python=3.6 --override-channels 
  --channel https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro 
  --channel https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free 
  --channel https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r 
  --channel https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2 
  --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion: Package not found: Conda could not find '
```

Running `pip install tensorflow`doesn't work either and returns:

```
Collecting tensorflow
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I updated to Python 3.6 and the last version of Anaconda (4.3.1, Py 3.6 version)

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: 4.3.1 is not the latest version of conda. 4.3.16 is. Please type `conda update conda` and then update the error messages you see after that.

Comment: @NehalJWani I just did it, and I had also tried with Anaconda 4.2 and Python 3.5, but the same message appears. Successfully installed with pip

Comment: Thank you all for helping anyway.

Comment: You can refer below thread..: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51016815/6835092